# Qooxdoo 1.6 Gzip option error

Tags: qooxdoo

I tried adding the 
`"gzip": true` option to my config.json file and get the following error:

- Generate packages  [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'apppath/build/script/appname.828e8d12c6a6.js'

I noticed there is a appname.828e8d12c6a6.js.gz file in the directory though.

Is there something else I need to change when I enable gzipping?

When I turn the gzip option to false, it completes successfully.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known regression in recent versions, and there is a [bug for it](http://bugzilla.qooxdoo.org/show_bug.cgi?id=5493) at the qooxdoo issue tracker. You might have to wait until that's fixed, I'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks #ThomasH! My searches didn't seem to come across that bug. Thanks for letting me know!